# How to remove multiple lines in files?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file where I need to remove some lines in the middle of the file.

The lines I need to remove have a keyword at the beginning and at the end.

Example:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
ccccccccccccccccc
ddddddddddddddddd
Begintoremove
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
fffffffffffffffff
ggggggggggggggggg
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
EndofRemove
iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj
kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
lllllllllllllllll
```

I need to have a script, certainly in python, to remove the text part between keyword "Begintoremove" and "EndofRemove".

Do you think it's possible to do, and if so, with which Python function?

Comment: I think yes, but you should try it first

Comment: of course it is possible to do, just try;-) . Read the file linewise and for each `line` you read use the function `line.startswith("Begintoremove")` to start removing until `line.startswith("EndRemove")` is True

Answer (score 2):

Read lines from the file and copy them to the second depending on the current `copying` state:

```
copying = True
with open('input_file.txt', 'rt') as inf, open('output_file.txt', 'wt') as outf:
    for line in inf:
        if copying:
            if line.startswith('Begintoremove'):
                copying = False
            else:
                outf.write(line)
        elif line.startswith('EndofRemove'):
            copying = True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open('filename')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

result = []
bool_remover = False
for line in lines:
    if line == "Begintoremove" : bool_remover = True
    if not bool_remover : result.append(line)
    if line == "EndofRemove" : bool_remover = False
```

I'm not including "Begintoremove" and "EndofRemove" in the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('file_path', 'r') as my_file:
    file_lines = my_file.readlines()

first_part = file_lines[:file_lines.index('Begintoremove')]
second_part = file_lines[file_lines.index('Endtoremove') + 1:]

lines = first_part + second_part
with open('file_path', 'w') as my_file:
    my_file.writelines(lines)
```